Suspended loss on 2 properties offset ira distribution income when 1 property is sold
I have two rental properties and will be selling one this year.

Property A has suspended loss of $120,000 and
Property B $100,000.

When I sell property A this year, I can write off $220,000 against my Roth conversion counted as income?
Assume no capital gain or loss on this sale of property A and I have no other income other than Ira distribution or Roth conversion.

I think you can only write off realized loss, meaning after the actual sale. Otherwise you'd also have to pay tax on unrealized gain.

Where does the @220,000 come from? Are you adding the 120 and the 100? Will you sell A for more than you paid for it? Not enough information for a complete answer.

Suspended loss from 2 properties are from unallowed loss deduction for passive income from the last 10 years accumulative. I can use the loss but have to sell the property. Question is can I use combined suspended loss of selling only 1 property? 2nd question is can I use that to offset Roth conversion which is reported as income for the year?  Assume no capital gain or loss from the sale of this property, not a capital gain question.
